# How to use version vectors to decide which value to keep?

Tags: distributed-systems

I am trying to understand how to build an eventually consistent KV store. It's just a learning experiment. Let's only consider one value which stores a fruits list.

We have 2 servers, 2 clients, N=2, W=1, R=1.

We start with an empty value and a zero version vector on both servers.

- Server 1 and 2: `('', {'Client-A': 0, 'Client-B': 0})`

Right from the beginning the updates do not reach all the servers like they should. Client A adds `'apple'` and bumps the version vector, but the update only reaches Server 1. Client B adds `'banana'` and bumps the version vector, but the update only reaches Server 2.

- Server 1: `('apple', {'Client-A': 1, 'Client-B': 0})`
- Server 2: `('banana', {'Client-A': 0, 'Client-B': 1})`

Now Client A reads from Server 2, adds `'mango'` and bumps the version vector, but unfortunately the update only reaches Server 1. There are 2 candidates values and version vectors for Server 1.

- `('apple', {'Client-A': 1, 'Client-B': 0})` (existing value)
- `('banana, mango', {'Client-A': 1, 'Client-B': 1})` (proposed value)

According to the version vectors the proposed value is a descendant of the existing one, so there is no conflict and we take the proposed value.

- Server 1: `('banana, mango', {'Client-A': 1, 'Client-B': 1})`

We lost an apple. What am I missing?

Comment: @D.W.: My understanding is that if a single server holds one value and version vector, then receives a concurrent update with the value it already holds, it will store both values and version vectors as a result. Is that wrong?

Comment: @D.W.: As I tried to give an example I realised my misunderstanding is even more basic than I thought it was. I edited the question *very* significantly. I hope it helps clarify what I don't understand.

Comment: When Client A reads from Server 2, it can see that the returned value is out-of-date (Client A knows that the `Client-A` version number should be at least 1, but the object received from the server has only version 0).

Comment: I agree that Client A can know that the value is out of date. However is it a practical solution in a real word scenario? Can we expect the clients to remember the version vector of each of the values they ever read? (In practice they can probably prune the list so it's really not as bad as I make it sound). I wouldn't think so, but again it appears that I don't understand this algorithm :)

Comment: Not the version vector of each of the values they ever read -- but each client *is* responsible for remembering its own version number.